# session recreation in HornetQ JMS

Tags: java

i am facing the problem with hornetq sessions.can any one give the solution for that.My Query is: how can we create new sessions instead of the closed ones in hornetq?Thanks in advance

Comment: connection.createSession()? provide details on what you are trying to do.